# wkhtmltopdf - Error 127 - Error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: php, lamp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I am in the process of migrating a site to Amazon Lightsail (Bitnami LAMP) and one of the libraries used is wkhtmltopdf.

After installing wkhtmltopdf on the new server I am running into the following error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

After using the strace tool I saw that the libXrender libraries were missing, so I installed them using following and then run an update:

> sudo apt-get install libxrender1

> sudo apt-get update